# Update SQL Query not working ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

Here is the code of my .aspx page,
When I click on update it runs the page doesn't show any errors and the row is not updated in my blog table.
The exception doesn't display anything, and i have a row with the id in my table.

The select command in the Page_Load() works perfectly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Blog
{
    public partial class update : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(##################);

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
            string sql = "select * from blog where Id=@id";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                DropDownListCategory.SelectedIndex = DropDownListCategory.Items.IndexOf(DropDownListCategory.Items.FindByText(dataReader["category"].ToString().Trim()));
                TextBoxTitle.Text = dataReader["title"].ToString();
                TextBoxDesc.Text = dataReader["description"].ToString();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LabelDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

        protected void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"].Trim());
                string sql2 = "UPDATE blog SET title = @title , category = @category , description = @description , posteddate = @posteddate WHERE Id=@id";
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand sqlCommand2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, connection);
                sqlCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                sqlCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", TextBoxTitle.Text);
                sqlCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", DropDownListCategory.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());
                sqlCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", TextBoxDesc.Text);
                sqlCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@posteddate", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                sqlCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = ex.Message;
            }
            connection.Close();
            //Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: check the output of sqlCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery() . Is it returning anything ?

Comment: try to return the result of 
int updated = sqlCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: that don't look like a null in the database - it suggests that the query or connection is not working in the first place.

Comment: sqlCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery(); returns 1

Comment: [SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection), [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand) and [SqlDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader) are all IDisposables that should be created and disposed of in `using` blocks. You could be getting SqlConnection into a weird state by trying to reuse it like this.

Comment: Also, [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) [AddWithValue() is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). You really should be using the SqlParameter overloads that supply a `SqlDbType` parameter for the correct SQL datatypes of your parameters.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString()` is just wrong, if it's a `DateTime` then pass it as such not as a `string` like this `DateTime.Now`

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the page after the update?

Answer (score 0):

Added a if(!IsPostBack){} now works fine, Thank you

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
                    string sql = "select * from blog where Id=@id";
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        DropDownListCategory.SelectedIndex = DropDownListCategory.Items.IndexOf(DropDownListCategory.Items.FindByText(dataReader["category"].ToString().Trim()));
                        TextBoxTitle.Text = dataReader["title"].ToString();
                        TextBoxDesc.Text = dataReader["description"].ToString();
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
```